# How to NOT force cast value from dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, casting

I have a snapshot(dictionary) that i get from the database that may or may not contain some values for some keys.

How can I safely ask for it and then not have to forcefully cast the variable or forcefully unwrap it later
This is what I have now:

```
let eventName = event?[FirebaseIdentifiers.EventName] as! String
```

But would like to maybe do something like this

```
let eventName = event?[FirebaseIdentifiers.EventName] as? String
```

but this would cause me to have to make an if let later in the code so i don't forcefully unwrap it.

Is there another elegant way maybe?

EDIT: to make question a bit clear

This is the original option i have and was hopping there might be something a bit better since I have about 20 variables that would create a bit if let statement that can be quite hard to read

```
 let eventName = event?[FirebaseIdentifiers.taEventName] as? String

            if let evName = eventName {

            }
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the value is not in the dictionary?

Comment: Use a default value?  `event?[FirebaseIdentifiers.EventName] as? String  ?? "none"`

Comment: Why not use a `guard` statement and exit early with an error if the value is `nil`?

Comment: @vacawama i just want to initialise the value with an empty string in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your second code snippet

```
let eventName = event?[FirebaseIdentifiers.EventName] as? String
```

if (evenName == nil), you have no idea is it **event == nil** or there is **no FirebaseIdentifiers.EventName** key-value pair in your dictionary

So my suggestion is to unwrap event first, then check if value exist.

```
guard let event = event else {
    // event dictionary == nil
    return
}
if let eventName = event[FirebaseIdentifiers.EventName] as? String {
    // exist
} else {
    // doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: that is my original oppinion but i was hopping there might be a less verbose way to do it than this

Answer (score 1):

You could consider storing a default value, like an empty string, if the key does not have a value. For example:

```
let eventName = event?[FirebaseIdentifiers.EventName] as? String ?? ""
```

So if you can't cast it to a String, then eventName stores "". This may not be the best solution, since you would then need to check if eventName is an empty string, but you won't need to forcefully unwrap it :)

Comment: I would advise against this. It completely defeats the purpose of using optionals in the first place.